# buttons are not playing the sound. I have included the wav file

Tags: swift, swift3

The buttons are not playing the sound?
How can you make the coding more correct?

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

//var  audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var  audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

        let path =  Bundle.main.path(forResource: "BtnSon", ofType: " WAV")
        let soundURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: (path)!)

        do {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
          audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
    }

    @IBAction  func numberPressed(Sender: UIButton){
          playSound()
    }

    func playSound(){
        if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
          audioPlayer.stop()
        }

        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Biffen  its same . it is showing an error : fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
(lldb)

Comment: You are using of type " wav" try "wav" without the leading space

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
import UIKit
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

//var  audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var  audioPlayer: AVAudioPlayer!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //--------------------------------------------------------> No space before _W
        guard let soundURL =  Bundle.main.url(forResource: "BtnSon", withExtension: "WAV") else {
            fatalError("You have failed to add 'BtnSon.WAV' in your app bundle.")
        }
        do {
            try audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: soundURL)
            audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
        }
    }

    @IBAction func numberPressed(_ sender: UIButton){
        playSound()
    }

    func playSound(){
        if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
            audioPlayer.stop()
        }
        audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

And be careful, iOS's file system is case-sensitive.